# Why does my component render twice when using React's Context API and the useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, react-context

I'm trying to understand how the Context API works together with React hooks (specifically `useEffect` and `useReducer`).
I am unsure as to why one of my components (`ContactListPage`) seems to be rendering twice.

A minimal example to demonstrate:

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <ContactContextProvider>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </ContactContextProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**contact-context.js**

```
export const ContactContext = createContext();

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_CONTACTS": {
      return { ...state, contacts: action.payload };
    }
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

export const ContactContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { contacts: [] });
  const store = React.useMemo(() => ({ state, dispatch }), [state, dispatch]);

  return (
    <ContactContext.Provider value={store}>
      {props.children}
    </ContactContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**ContactListPage.js**

```
export default function ContactListPage() {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(ContactContext);
  console.log(state);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        // Make Ajax request for contacts here
        dispatch({
          type: "FETCH_CONTACTS",
          payload: [{ name: "Bob" }]
        });
      } catch (error) {
        // handle error
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>List of Contacts</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is [the app running in a CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-archimedes-jik7r?file=/src/App.js).

When the `ContactListPage` component first renders, the following is logged to the console:

```
Object {contacts: Array[0]}
Object {contacts: Array[1]}
```

This makes sense to me. Initially the `contacts` array is empty, then in the `useEffect` hook in the `ContactListPage` component, I dispatch an action to add a contact, so the component is re-rendered with the updated list of contacts.

The problem comes when I navigate away from this view (I'm using React Router), then I navigate back. In this case I see:

```
Object {contacts: Array[1]}
Object {contacts: Array[1]}
```

I would have expected the `console.log` statement to only fire once, as the contacts array hasn't changed.

I've spent all afternoon Googling this. None of the other answers I could find on SO worked for me.

**So, my question is**: Why does the `console.log` statement always fire twice?

---

N.B. To reproduce this in the CodeSandbox:

- Click on the *Add Contact* link and observe the first output in CodeSandbox's console.
- Click on the *Contacts List* link and observe the second output in CodeSandbox's console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the `useEffect` implementation here takes place when the component is rendered for the first time. Thats when you get the result:

```
Object {contacts: Array[0]} Object {contacts: Array[1]}
```

Since you are still in the app, the action dispatched at the first render of the component is saved in the state. Since you have navigated away component .i.e. the component is not longer in dom, when you load component again in dom, hence after the initial render, the `useEffect` takes place and renders your component after the effect is completed because you are dispatching another action to the reducer even though you have the value.

Since a new action is dispatched, that is considered as a state change and that is when you see following:

```
Object {contacts: Array[1]} Object {contacts: Array[1]}
```

You can test this by add `console.log` at this line in your reducer:

Now you can add something like a check or a flag that can confirm that the data has been loaded and you don't have to make the fetch again.

So I have added following check in your `useEffect`:

```
 if (state.contacts.length === 0) {
      fetchData();
 }
```

And Eureka !!! One less render.

I have tried out and modified your sandbox on this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-dew-pj149?file=/src/components/ContactListPage.js:524-584). So it is nice to have these check incase you want to minimise unnecessary call and renders on the app.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your component is mounting again when you change your route. So when you go from `contact list` to `add contact`:

Your reducer already set it to `name:bob`

And now again when your come back to your `component list` component. Two things is happening component is rendering because of `useContext` inital state(hooks also cause rerendering) and another one is causing because of your `useEffect` i.e you are dispatching your `FETCH_CONTACTS` when component is mounted.

If you see console on first load:

```
Object {contacts: Array[0]} 
Object {contacts: Array[1]}
```

Observe console return two statement first state is when contact is empty and second state is when contact is updated using reducer]

Now when you come from add contact page the console shows this:

```
Object {contacts: Array[1]}
Object {contacts: Array[1]}
```

Both has same value first one coming from context intital state and second one is coming again as reducer is again updating value.

If you want to see yourself add console more for clarity. Check here how component is mounting and unmounting: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-ishizaka-enck6?file=/src/components/ContactListPage.js:478-492